# How to to define a custom Class within strdist function of SOLR?

Tags: solr

In the Documentation for SOLR Function Queries, it is mentioned that the function strdist allows user-defined functions, but I am unable to find any documentation on how to implement the same. Requesting assistance.

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/function-queries.html

[strdist documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgbtU.png)

Edit: I am sharing the snippet of my solrconfig.xml where I have defined the 3rd Party Lib, and where I defined a valueSourceParser.

```
<lib dir="D:/Software/solr-8.4.1/third_party_lib" regex="commons-text-1.9.jar"/>
<valueSourceParser name="myfunc" class="org.apache.commons.text.similarity.CosineSimilarity" />
```

When I try to Start the core I am getting the below Error.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Initiating valueSourceParser, org.apache.common.text.similaity.CosineSimilarity failed to initiate org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser
```

[SOLR Core Start up Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OrPY.png)

Comment: What you're doing in your additional thing is to try to use a _similarity_ class to calculate string distance. Similarity classes generate a score for comparison between documents, they do _not_ do anything related to string distance. Neither do that class implement the `StringDistance` interface. You have to follow the rules of the function (i.e. a class that implements `StringDistance`) and give it the kind of class that it expects.

Answer (score 0):

The last example of the `strdist` description tells you want to send in:

> **FQN**: Fully Qualified class Name for an implementation of the StringDistance interface. Must have a no-arg constructor.

It expects you to give it a fully qualified Java class name that can be loaded through the regular class loader (so available in a jar file, for example) that implements the `StringDistance` interface. So using something like `org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevenshteinDistance` should work as a test.

You can see [the relevant loader](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/9bfaca0606968ed970d9d12d871f977e2655765b/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/ValueSourceParser.java#L422) code and [an example implementation (for the JW mode)](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/1bb9755e4acf09677b36fdc0e60a9ea9889ea115/lucene/suggest/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/JaroWinklerDistance.java).